# absolute value in cplex c++

Tags: visual-c++, absolute, cplex

I have to use absolute value in the cost function of some linear problem.
Part that bother me like this

```
for (t=0;t<T;t++)  
   for (i=0;i<I; i++){  
     for (j=1;j<J; j++) 
       Sum += |x[i][j][t]-x[i][j][t-1]|*L/2;
     Sum += |x[i][0][t]-x[i][0][t-1]|*V/2;  
   }
```

I am writing my code in c++ and I don't know how to implement absolute value. x is integer value. 
I have tried with cplex.getValue(x[i][j][t])-cplex.getValue(x[i][j][t-1]) >0 but it couldn't work.

Comment: What is the type of x ?

Comment: Also, your code is very broken - you are trying to access index t - 1 when t starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Since the absolute value function is nonlinear ( the reason is explained in [this math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88669) question ) you need to linearize the objective function first.

Basically, you need to express each absolute-valued-term of that summation with a new variable and optimize the sum of these new variables (subject to some additional constraints). The method is explained in detail in Section 7.2 of [Linear Programming](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/LP.pdf) textbook of Thomas S. Ferguson.